# I want to set different colors to the part filled and unfilled of a progress bar programmatically how can i do it?

Tags: android

here's my code but using this the color changes for the whole progressbar

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
int greyColor= Color.rgb(248,248,248);
```

Comment: https://azzits.wordpress.com/tag/multiple-color-progressbar/ here is sample .. hope it might help you

Comment: Check this tutorial https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Progress-Bar-Custom-View and you can customize the code to your needs

Comment: @Raghunandan it worked but when i wanted to integrated in a listview it didn't work dou you have any idea how can i resolve it thank you so much

Comment: Post your code with relevant details

Comment: @Raghunandan i can't post it here!! do i have to set another question ?

Comment: @Raghunandan i have reached the question limit the problem is the listview doesn't show the progressivebar i think it's related to ButterKnife